# Update em uma linha da tabela

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sql-update

Estou começando a utilizar o **SQLite** em um projeto e gostaria de uma ajuda em como fazer o `update` em uma linha específica, neste caso, será atualizado somente um "ID" de cada vez.

Segue os códigos:

View e onde está o click no botão para update:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //recupera o estado da posição atual
        final UserCommunity inviteUsers = usersList.get(position);

        //Cria uma instancia do layout .. na view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_invite_listview,null);

        TextView txt_Nome = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_nome_invite);
        TextView txt_Email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_email_invite);
        TextView txt_Distancia = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_distancia_invite);
        ImageButton btn_Share = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.img_invite);

        txt_Nome.setText(inviteUsers.name);
        txt_Email.setText(inviteUsers.email);
        txt_Distancia.setText(Integer.toString(inviteUsers.distance));

        btn_Share.setTag(position);
        btn_Share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(AppController.getAppContext(),"Enviado para: "+inviteUsers.name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                usersList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                service.upddateDataBase(inviteUsers.id,true);
            }
        });
}
```

Service com o método para update (como fazer?):

```
public class InviteUsersService {

    public void upddateDataBase(int id, boolean b) {

    }
}
```

Código do banco: (Campo a ser alterado "invited BOOLEAN")

```
@Override

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists users ( " +
        "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        "name TEXT, "+
        "email TEXT, "+
        "company TEXT, "+
        "photo_url TEXT, "+
        "departure_time TEXT, "+
        "arrival_time TEXT, "+
        "address_lat DOUBLE,"+
        "address_lng DOUBLE,"+
        "invited BOOLEAN)";

// create books table
db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);

}
```

Comment: Leia [este](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) tutorial. Se tiver alguma dúvida nele edite sua pergunta.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: Seria esta a resposta?
    public void upddateDataBase(int id, boolean b) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        String where = "where id =?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};

        values.put(KEY_INVITED,b);

        db.update(TABLE_USERS,values,where,whereArgs);

    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void upddateDataBase(int id, boolean b) { 
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
String where = "where id =?";
 String[] whereArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}; values.put(KEY_INVITED,b); db.update(TABLE_USERS,values,where,whereArgs); 
}
```

Resposta para a questão.